# If I look at my watch at T23:59:59+01:00, what should I expect to see?

Tags: time, timezone

I'm a bit lost on a very simple matter. Let's say I'm in a +01:00 timezone and I look at my clock, regulated on the current timezone, at T23:59:59+01:00. I'm expecting to see this:

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/dDcQ8MBm/23-59.png]

Am I right?

If then I fly to a +XY:00 timezone, I adjust my clock accordingly and then I look at my clock at the same local time, T23:59:59+XY:00, I'm expecting to see the same image.

Generally speaking: the format just means "hey, world! this is the time I mean locally, just beware I'm +XY hours ahead".

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, yes - the majority of clocks show the time and don't inform you of the timezone. People will eat lunch at 12:00 (or around there) in whatever timezone you are. Unless that's something like China (single timezone for the entire country) but *overall* the point remains - local time is local time. If people wake up at 07:00 and go to bed at 23:00 in one timezone, in another the locals will do the same thing. I'm not sure how is that a programming question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `T23:59:59+01:00` means that the time *here* is 23:59:59, and *here* is +1 hours away from UTC.

It's as if you're calling a friend of yours and saying that "the time *here* is 23:59, and we're GMT+1".

If you feed your time string to PHP as a new DateTime object:

```
$string = "T23:59:59+01:00";
$dt = new DateTime("@".strtotime($string));
var_dump($dt);
```

PHP will take that time and translate it to the server's local time (in my case, UTC+0), and include the timezone:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-03-06 22:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

I can change the timezone of the datetime object:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('EST');
$dt->setTimezone($timezone);
var_dump($dt);
```

PHP will then display the time in the new timezone, and again, include the timezone:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-03-06 17:59:59.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "EST"
}
```